# Varcar(200) in mySql does not match maxLength=200 attribute of html textarea

Tags: mysql, maxlength

I am using MySql database and for a field I chose varchar(200) . To prevent issues I set on my html page maxlength 200 . So ideally there should be no problem . But If I let the user input 200 characters I get exception. So i tried and tried and only at 190 characters I can be sure it also fits the database. So in future I will to prevent issues always make size of varchar() 20% bigger than what user can input in html page.

Answer (score 1):

May be `carriage returns` are considered 2 characters each when it comes to maxlength. Can you make sure, you have any carriage returns.

```
1\r\n
1\r\n
1\r\n
1
```

[image]

Comment: textarea maxlength already counts carriage returns. Let's say you have maxlength= 10 and you enter 5 characters , after each you press enter , that is the minimum maxlength allows because you already have 10 characters now. So now for me it is even weirder why mqsql gives me exception

Answer (score 1):

A `varchar(200)` should be able to store 200 characters. You shouldn't need to increase the size, but if you do, an arbitrary 10% increase won't guarantee to solve the problem unless you know what is causing it. The danger of an overflow will remain.

Some possible reasons that spring to mind:

- As noted by @VigneshKumarA, it could be carriage returns being stored as two characters.
- It could also be multibyte unicode characters -- ie anything other than the basic ASCII character set. If you're entering accented letters or symbols, or non-Latin scripts, they will take up more than one byte per character.
- Escaped/encoded characters, if you are sanitising your data. For example if you're running `htmlentities()` or similar on the input string, you may be getting single characters from the input being converted into entity codes like `&amp;`. This will obviously make the string longer than it was when input.

What I would recommend is that you use a database tool to examine the stored data and check to see why it is storing more characters than you expected. Understand what the discrepancy is caused by, and then either fix it or adapt your system to handle it so that you can be sure it will never overflow.

Comment: so I just entered 200 A's . So when I directly go to mysql database no problem to enter 200 A's . Also no problem to enter 200 A's in my browser window. But it seems when my server sends it to the database maybe at this point it is more than 200 characters. I am using jdbc and ORM

Comment: it seems there is something on the server code. So I will check this. Thanks for your help @all